# Fill 3x3 magic square with distinct numbers 1..60 summing up to 69

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, magic-square, calculation-puzzle

I have to fill a whole 3x3 grid in such a way that the sum of each row, column, and main diagonal is 69. I couldn't find any logic to fill it up. I have to use **distinct** numbers from 1 to 60 for this. Here's the square:

$\begin{align}
    &x_0&x_1& &x_2\\
    &y_0&y_1& &y_2\\
    &z_0&z_1& &z_2
\end{align}$

All values $\{x_i, y_i, z_i\}$ should be less than 60.

$\left.\begin{align}
x_0+y_0+z_0=69\\
x_1+y_1+z_1=69\\
x_2+y_2+z_2=69\\
\end{align}\right\}\text{columns}\\$

$\left.\begin{align}
x_0+x_1+x_2=69\\
y_0+y_1+y_2=69\\
z_0+z_1+z_2=69\\
\end{align}\right\}\text{rows}$

$\left.\begin{align}
x_0+y_1+z_2=69\\
x_2+y_1+z_0=69
\end{align}\right\}\text{diagonals}$

Can anyone help me out??

Answer (score 10):

The easiest way is just to take all 23's and...

> subtract 5, then add back the standard 3x3 magic square.

So the solution is:

> 22 27 20
>  21 23 25
>  26 19 24

Comment: Might want to add the standard magic square for reference.

Answer (score 5):

*This is essentially the same answer as Deusovi, but I thought I'd try to explain things a little better...*

---

There is a well-known [magic square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_square) using the numbers from $1$ to $9$:

$\begin{align}
    &2&7& &6\\
    &9&5& &1\\
    &4&3& &8
\end{align}$

In this square, all the rows, columns, and diagonals add up to $15 = \left(\frac{\text{max}+\text{min}}2\right)\times3$.

In your square, you want the numbers to add up to $69$.  You can use the formula above to determine the $\text{max}$ and $\text{min}$ values for your square:

$69 = \left(\frac{\text{max}+\text{min}}2\right)\times3\\
\frac{69}3 = \frac{\text{max}+\text{min}}2\\
23 = \frac{\text{max}+\text{min}}2\\
2\times23 = \text{max}+\text{min}\\
\text{max} + \text{min} = 46$

If you want to use consecutive numbers in your square, then the difference between $\text{max}$ and $\text{min}$ needs to be $8$ (just like $9-1$). (If you don't want consecutive numbers in your square, you can count by $2$s (difference $16$), or $3$s (difference $24$), etc.)

Solving for $x+(x+8)=46$ gives $2x=38$, so $x=19$.  That will be the lowest number in your square.

$19-1=18$ (*lowest number in your square* $-$ *lowest number in standard square*)

So just add $18$ to every number in the standard square, and you'll have your magic square for $69$:

$\begin{align}
    &20&25& &24\\
    &27&23& &19\\
    &22&21& &26
\end{align}$

Note that there are many other solutions, some of which might not use a "standard" magic square (there might not be a regular interval between each of the entries in the square).

Answer (score 4):

27048 such matrices exist. I present you a few:

```
============
Matrix 1
21 23 25
29 22 18
19 24 26
============
Matrix 2
21 29 19
23 22 24
25 18 26
============
Matrix 3
22 23 24
29 21 19
18 25 26
============
```

Rest (including these) are present [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7E86owOgl-PallIdVNteFdMM3M/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: While these do satisfy the problem as presented in the question, the OP did clarify in the comments that the values must be distinct.

Comment: @BruceDoh updated

Comment: Your diagonal (bottom-left to top-right) is not 69. Your full list also use the number 0.

Answer (score 3):

Just put 23 at the center and let two squares at the corners of the same edge be $a$ and $b$, then calculate the others based on these two. Just make sure they're all distinct. For example:

|  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 15 | 44 | 10 |
| 18 | 23 | 28 |
| 36 | 2 | 31 |